# Is it possible to to pipe `put_in` calls on a struct?

Tags: elixir

Given a map, it's possible to write something like:

```
mymap
|> put_in([:foo, :bar], "hello")
|> put_in([:attr1], "how are you")
|> put_in([:attr2], "goodbye")
```

Ideally, I'd be able to do the same with a struct:

```
mystruct
|> put_in(.foo.bar, "hello")
|> put_in(.attr1, "how are you")
|> put_in(.attr2, "goodbye")
```

Is something like this possible? Currently I'm writing:

```
mystruct = put_in(mystruct.foo.bar, "hello")
mystruct = put_in(mystruct.attr1, "how are you")
put_in(mystruct.attr, "goodbye")
```

It gets the job done but isn't as elegant as using the pipe operator.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can use `put_in` with structs. Here's what you want, for anyone stumbling upon this later:

```
mymap
|> put_in([:foo, :bar] |> Enum.map(&Access.key/1), "hello")
|> put_in([Access.key(:attr1)], "how are you")
|> put_in([Access.key(:attr2)], "goodbye")
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a capture

```
mymap
|> put_in([:foo, :bar], "hello")
|> put_in([:attr1], "how are you")
|> put_in([:attr2], "goodbye")
```

should work.

---

edit: only works for maps. `put_in` does not work for structs because they don't implement the `access` protocol.

Comment: @jisaacestone The edited code still errors out. I went through the docs and found that `put_in/3` requires the first argument to implement the Access behaviour. Structs don't implement Access, so it looks like piping a struct into `put_in` isn't possible at the moment.

Comment: yes you are correct, I was using maps ... apologies.